RRweb on server side
I have created an instance of RRwebPlayer on the server side in a Node.js environment to use the Mirror functionality and fetch updated nodes. My setup involves the following steps:
Creating a Virtual DOM Environment:
I am using jsdom to create a virtual DOM environment on the server side.
Initializing `RRwebPlayer:
I initialized the Replayer instance with some initial events like full snapshots and incremental events.
Adding Incremental Events:
I am using the addEvent function of RRwebPlayerInstance to add incremental events.
Issue:
The Mirror instance is not getting updated with the incremental events (may be it is due to error window.scroll not found while intialization of rrwebPlayerInstance with intialEvents).
Although I can get the Mirror instance with initial values and properties, it does not reflect the changes from the incremental events.
Request:
How can I ensure that the Mirror instance gets updated with the incremental events?
Are there any additional steps or configurations needed to make this work correctly in a Node.js environment using jsdom and rrdom-nodejs?
I am trying live streaming of events in node js environment
